# marionette.js controller this.options parameter in initialize

Tags: javascript, controller, marionette

well, I have a marionette.js controller and it has an initialize function (this code was passed to me by someone else). In this code I found that the initialize function contains a @options parameter. Where does it come from? Does anyone know if, for example, in the router you can pass the controller somehow any parameters? By the way this is my file (I am using require.js and node):

```
define (require, exports, module) ->
   # framework dependencies
   Marionette = require 'Backbone.Marionette'

   # Actions
   ShowLandingPageAction = require '../actions/show-landing-page-action'

   class LandingPageController extends Marionette.Controller
      initialize: (@options)->
         @region = options.region

      showLandingPage: ->
         console.log '--showLandingPage--'
         action =  new ShowLandingPageAction
         action.execute @region
         @trigger 'set:active:home'

   module.exports = LandingPageController
```

Comment: Options get passed in when you initialize the Controller. So, when you have `new LandingPageController({ test: true })`, `{test: true}` would be your options.

Answer (score 2):

The options are the values that are passed to the controller when it is created:

```
var controller = new LandingPageController({
    one: 1,
    two: 2
});
```

The object that is passed are your options, so in other words, you'd have access to the `on` and `two` attributes with (e.g.) `options.one`.